# Aggregate then split with Apache Camel

Tags: scala, apache-camel

After aggregation, i'm trying to split an exchange that is a group of exchanges. But inside the split the elements of the group are null.

I'm using apache camel 2.17 (camel-core, camel-ftp and camel-scala)

```scala
from("sftp://user@host/path?password=pass")
.setHeader("tag", extractTagFromFilename)
.aggregate(header("tag"), new GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy())
.completionSize(3) // i want 3 files per group
.split(_.in)
     .process{m => println("== > " + m.in[])}
.end()
//.process{m => println("")} // btw this does not compile, why ?
.log("${body}")
```

== > null

== > null

== > null

Why the elements in the group are null ?

Comment: What's the reason of the downvote ?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, the aggreg strategy must be GroupedMessageAggregationStrategy instead of GroupedExchangeAggregationStrategy.

It's really painfull that the documentation is not up-to-date, it should be mentioned that ".groupExchanges()" is deprecated and the GroupedMessageAggregationStrategy should be used to get a simple list based aggregation.